# htaccess, не работает подгрузка любых файлов по другому урлу

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Доброго всем времени суток!
Не могу разобраться с подгрузкой файлов стилей/скриптов/картинок по другому урлу.

Я все до ужаса упростил, для того чтобы вам было проще объяснить в чем заключается мой принципиальный завтык..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule .* aaa.css [L]
```

этот код должен вместо любых запрашиваемых файлов подкидывать aaa.css из корня.. но мне браузер все время выдает 404 ошибку.

Я подозревал кучу ошибок, например типа забыл я AllowOverride выставить в All.. Но все вроде на месте т.к. если я пробую поменять

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule .* aaa.css [L]
```

то редирект срабатывает при любом запросе не файлов, а просто любого урла, меня выкидывает на aaa.css файлик.. т.е. дело в RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
Возможно я не подключил что-то необходимое для работы этих условий или просто неверно понял всю парадигму работы htaccess

Объясните хотя бы в какую сторону копать... Заранее всем низкий поклон за ответы. любые!

Comment: Вы тут написали `RewriteRule .* aaa.css [L]` что все запросы обрабатывать через `aaa.css` а должны просто проигнорировать этот `aaa.css` и сервер должен будет его отдать. Т.е. просто переименуйте или удалите htaccess. И вопрос, собственно какой результат нужен?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть логи `mod_rewrite`: добавьте в .htaccess строки `RewriteLog /var/log/rewrite.log` и `RewriteLogLevel 3` путь к лог файлу свой

Comment: конечная цель нужно чтобы с файлы подгружаемые с адреса 
domain.ru/test/content/style.css
загружались с
domain.ru/content/style.css
но регулярку я и сам напишу мне нужно разобраться с описанной выше ситуацией, чтобы понять картину целиком.как сделать так чтобы при запросе ЛЮбого файла выводился aaa.css?